# How to convert hexlified binary data to unicode string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to "decode" a Unicode string from a [hexlified](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) binary data on node.js.

```
const convert = (from, to) => (str) => Buffer.from(str, from).toString(to);
const hexToUtf8 = convert('hex', 'utf8');
const content = hexToUtf8(data.binary)
```

But when I send the following data:

> Sent from your Twilio trial account - ¿Cómo estás?

It's getting converted as

> Sent from your Twilio trial account - �C�mo est�s?

The binary data was `53656e742066726f6d20796f7572205477696c696f20747269616c206163636f756e74202d20bf43f36d6f20657374e1733f`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you bytes were encoded as latin1:

```
let data = "53656e742066726f6d20796f7572205477696c696f20747269616c206163636f756e74202d20bf43f36d6f20657374e1733f"
let b = Buffer.from(data, 'hex')
console.log(b.toString('latin1'))
```

**Prints**

```
Sent from your Twilio trial account - ¿Cómo estás?
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I don't really know the encoding beforehand. It can be a Chinese text too.

Comment: For example, this one contains a Chinese text: `00530065006e0074002000660072006f006d00200079006f007500720020005400770069006c0069006f00200074007200690061006c0020006100630063006f0075006e00740020002d00204e0956fd6f144e49`

Comment: If you don't know how the characters are converted to hex it's going to be really hard to decode. For instance above á is encoded as `e1` in latin1. It would be two bytes: `c3a1` in utf8, which in latin1 is something like `Ã¡`. But who's to say `Ã¡` isn't correct? That's why this has been such in issue  and why adoption of unicode is so helpful.